# Wix - How to distinguish registry key with no default value from no registry key

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Given the following...

```
<Property Id="TESTSEARCH">
   <RegistrySearch Id="LookingForKeyExists"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="Software\Classes\.ext"
                  Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

... I can get one of three conditions.

1. The key is not present
2. The key is present but not set
3. The key is present and has a value

I would like to be able to tell the difference between the following conditions.

```
<Condition Message="The extension .ext is missing">
    ???
</Condition>
<Condition Message="The extension .ext has no default value">
    ???
</Condition>
```

But all I've been able to find/figure out is the OR of the two.

```
<Condition Message="The extension .ext is either missing or does not have a default value">
    TESTSEARCH
</Condition>
```

Can the two separate conditions be distinguished without writing an extension? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible and it looks like Windows Installer limitation, rather than WiX toolset. [This original article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa371171.aspx) states that explicitly:

> *Note that it is not possible to use the RegLocator table to check only
>   for the presence of the key.* However, you can search for the default
>   value of a key and retrieve its value if it is not empty.